# need to use mootools for simple script instead of jquery... how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

i have a script in jquery (that grabs a value from a select field and transfers it to an input field) that i need to do in mootools...i love jquery... mootools i dont know...
not having much luck...
here is the code:

```
<select size="1" class="inputbox select "
    id="producers" name="producers">
    <option selected="selected" value="">- Select an Article -</option>
    <option value="86">Acetaia Leonardi</option>
    <option value="50">Esperidia</option>
    <option value="49">Frescobaldi Laudemio</option>
    <option value="85">Primitivizia</option>
    <option value="87">Principato Lucedio</option>
    <option value="51">Rustichella d'Abruzzo</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="" size="32" maxlength="50"
    name="producernamem" id="producernamem"
    class="inputbox text required required-enabled">
<!-- [example js] begin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#producers').change(function () {
        pselected = $('#producers option:selected').text();
        $("input#producernamem[type='text']").val(pselected);
        alert (pselected);
    });
});
</script>
```

---

sorry i think i flubbed that by not wrapping the code...

```
<select size="1" class="inputbox select " id="producers" name="producers"><option selected="selected" value="">- Select an Article -</option><option value="86">Acetaia Leonardi</option><option value="50">Esperidia</option><option value="49">Frescobaldi Laudemio</option><option value="85">Primitivizia</option><option value="87">Principato Lucedio</option><option value="51">Rustichella d'Abruzzo</option></select>

<input type="text" value="" size="32" maxlength="50" name="producernamem" id="producernamem" class="inputbox text required required-enabled">
<!-- [example js] begin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//<![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#producers').change(function () {
  pselected = $('#producers option:selected').text();
  $("input#producernamem[type='text']").val(pselected);

      alert (pselected);
  });
      });

    //]]>-->
</script>
```

Comment: To be displayed as code, it needs to be marked as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MooTools documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core) is a good resource for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('producers').addEvent('change', function(e){
        pselected = this.getSelected().get('text');
        $("producernamem").set('value', pselected);
        alert(pselected)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this throws the following error: this.getSelected is not a function
[Break on this error] (117 out of range 100)

Comment: sorry this may be the fault of some underlying ajax functionality. the script looks like it should work but for some reason i think mootools is not being seen. will get back to you when i figure it out.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/NBBR8/ it works with mootools 1.2+ (1.2.4 here).

it may be an issue with .getSelected() if you're on mootools 1.1x (but then .get("text") and .set("value") will also throw errors).

Comment: ahhh... you are right. when i delete all that and just do a helloworld alert it works. are there equivalencies for the older version of mootools?